# Sum of two array from different method

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio

I have a small program to roll two dices. So the user should enter a number to be the frequency number of the dice to be rolled when user click start, the program will show two different column with each fill with random number based on frequency which user inputted.

The program looks like this:

[image: rolldice]

After the random number showed up. The program will sum the random numbers (i filled the random numbers inside an array for each dices), I'm confuse, how can I sum two array from different method?

This is my code so far:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    firstDice();
    secondDice();
}
Random vran = new Random();
void firstDice()
{
    string temp = null;
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    int[] arr = new int[x];
    for (int i = 0;i<x;i++)
    {
        int a = vran.Next(1, 6);
        arr[i] = a;
        temp += a + " ";
        textBox2.Text = temp;
    }
}
void secondDice()
{
    string temp = null;
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    int[] arr = new int[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        int a = vran.Next(1, 6);
        arr[i] = a;
        temp += a + " ";
        textBox3.Text = temp;
    }
}
```

Notes: the array will sum for each value (i.e array[0] + array[0].. and so on).

Comment: Have each method return its array. `button1_Click` could then sum the arrays they return.

Comment: @EdPlunkett could you please show me how its done? since Im confuse on how to return each element of array/

Comment: Return the array. `int[] secondDice() { /* ...stuff...*/ return arr; }`

Comment: I have no idea what that means, sorry.

Comment: Im sorry that was a stupid question tho, I have figured it out the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to return an array from each of your `firstDice` and `secondDice` methods so that you can sum the two of them in your `button1_Click` method.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[] d1 = firstDice();
    int[] d2 = secondDice();
    // Assuming d1 and d2 are always of the same length
    int[] sum = new int[d1.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < sum.Length; i++)
    {
        sum[i] = d1[i] + d2[i];
    }
}
Random vran = new Random();
int[] firstDice()
{
    string temp = null;
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    int[] arr = new int[x];
    for (int i = 0;i<x;i++)
    {
        int a = vran.Next(1, 6);
        arr[i] = a;
        temp += a + " ";
        textBox2.Text = temp;
    }
    return arr;
}
int[] secondDice()
{
    string temp = null;
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    int[] arr = new int[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        int a = vran.Next(1, 6);
        arr[i] = a;
        temp += a + " ";
        textBox3.Text = temp;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your code corrected to do what you wanted. First note that both `firstDice()` and `secondDice()` now return an array of integers. Then in `button1_Click` a `for` loop iterates through each array element and sums them up, the result is put back in `array1`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int[] array1 = firstDice();
     int[] array2 = secondDice();
     for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
     {
         array1[i] += array2[i];
     }
}
Random vran = new Random();
int[] firstDice()
{
     string temp = null;
     int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
     int[] arr = new int[x];
     for (int i = 0;i<x;i++)
     {
          int a = vran.Next(1, 6);
          arr[i] = a;
          temp += a + " ";
          textBox2.Text = temp;
     }
     return arr;
}
int[] secondDice()
{
     string temp = null;
     int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
     int[] arr = new int[x];
     for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
     {
         int a = vran.Next(1, 6);
         arr[i] = a;
         temp += a + " ";
         textBox3.Text = temp;
     }
     return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare private variables under the class, and use them like this :

```
private int firstDiceSum = 0;
private int secondDiceSum = 0;
private int totalSum = 0;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    firstDice();
    secondDice();

    // Sum
    totalSum = firstDiceSum + secondDiceSum;

    //Show it to the user 
    textBox4.Text = totalSum.ToString();
}

Random vran = new Random();

void firstDice()
{
    string temp = null;
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    int[] arr = new int[x];
    for (int i = 0;i<x;i++)
    {
        int a = vran.Next(1, 6);
        arr[i] = a;
        temp += a + " ";
        textBox2.Text = temp;

        //add this 
        firstDiceSum += a;
    }
}

void secondDice()
{
    string temp = null;
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    int[] arr = new int[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        int a = vran.Next(1, 6);
        arr[i] = a;
        temp += a + " ";
        textBox3.Text = temp;

        //add this 
        secondDiceSum += a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code using only 1 method for generating the dice rolls. You can use use [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Join_System_String_System_Object___) to concatenate the array and [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.7.2) to sum. Also note that the max value of `Random.Next` [is exclusive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netframework-4.8#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_), so if you want `6` to be included, it must be `7`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int frequency = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    var firstDice = RollDice(textBox2,frequency);
    var secondDice = RollDice(textBox3,frequency);
    textBox4.Text = string.Join(" ",firstDice.Zip(secondDice, (x,y)=> x+y));
}
Random vran = new Random();
int[] RollDice(TextBox display, int frequency)
{    
    int[] arr = new int[frequency];
    for (int i = 0; i<frequency; i++)
    {
        int a = vran.Next(1, 7); //If you want 6 inclusive you should change to 7
        arr[i] = a;        
    }
    display.Text = string.Join(" ", arr);
    return arr;
}
```